# ASP Mvc Nhibernate Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, transactions

I am experiencing some bizarre problems with Nhibernate within my MVC web application.

There is not 1 consistent error, I keep getting loads of random ones:

- Transaction not successfully started
- New request is not allowed to start because it should come with valid transaction descriptor
- Unexpected row count: -1; expected: 1

To give a little context to the setup, I am using Ninject to DI the sessions and other Nhibernate related objects, currently I am using RequestScope however I have tried SingletonScope. I have a large and complicated data model, which is read out as a whole, but persisted back in separate parts, as these can all be edited and saved individually.

An example would be having a Customer object, which contains a address object, a contact object, friends object, previous orders object etc etc...

So the whole object is read out, then mapped to the UI domain models and then displayed in different partials within the page. Each partial can be updated individually via ajax, so you may update 1 section or you could update them all together. It seems mainly to give me the problems when I try to persist them all together (so 2-4 simultanious ajax requests to persist chunks of the model).

Now I have integration tests that work fine, which just test the persistence and retrieval of entities. As a whole and individually and all pass fine, however in the web app they just seem to keep throwing random exceptions, and originally refused to persist outside of the Nhibernate cache. I found a way round this by wrapping most units of work within transactions, which got the data persisting but started adding new errors to the mix.

Originally I was thinking of just scrapping Nhibernate from the project, as although I really want its persistance/caching layer, it just didnt seem to be flexible enough for my domain, which seems odd as I have used it before without much problem, although it doesn't like 1-1 mappings.

So has anyone else had flakey transaction/nhibernate issues like this within an ASP MVC app... I know this may be a bit vague as the errors dont point to one thing, and it doesn't always error, so its like stabbing in the dark, but I am out of ideas so any help would be great!

-- Update --

I cannot post all relevant code as the project is huge, but the transaction bit looks like:

```
using (var transaction = sessionManager.Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Do unit of work
                    transaction.Commit();

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Some of the main problems I have had on this project have stemmed from:

- There are some 1-1 relationships with composite keys, but logically it makes sense
- The Nhibernate domain entities go through a mapping layer to become the UI domain entities, then vice versa when saving. Problem here is that with the 1-1 mappings, when persisting the example Address I have to make a Surrogate Customer object with the correct Id then merge.
- There is ALOT of Ajax that deals with chunks of the overall model (I talk like there is one single model, but there are quite a few top level models, just one that is most important)

Comment: Could you post code samples on how objects are saved and transaction management is done?

Comment: Is it possible that you're inadvertently nesting your sessions/transactions and/or not opening sessions/beginning transactions where you think you are? Do you have the session/transaction logic in multiple places? Have you given any thought to using the session-per-request pattern using an HttpModule?

Answer (score 0):

Some notes that may help. I use windsor but imagine the concepts are the same. Sounds like there may be a combination of things.

- SessionFactory should be created as singleton and session should be per web request. Something like:

  ```
      Bind<ISessionFactory>()
          .ToProvider<SessionFactoryBuilder>()
          .InSingletonScope();

      Bind<ISession>()
          .ToMethod( context => context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession() )
          .InRequestScope();
  ```
- Be careful of keeping transactions open for too long, keep them as short lived as possible to avoid deadlocks.
- Check your queries are running as as expected by using a tool like NHProf. Often people load up too much of the graph which impacts performance and can create deadlocks.
- Check your mappings for things like not.lazyload() and see if you actually need the additional data in the queries and keep results returned to a min. Check your queries execution plans and ensure adequate indexes are in place.
- I have had issues with mvc3 action filters being cached, which meant transactions were not always started, but would attempt to be closed causing issues. Moved all my transaction commits into ActionResults in the controllers to keep transaction as short as possible and close to the action.
- Check your cascades in your mappings and keep the updates to a minimum.